# How do I assign an TextInput to an int, in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, textinput, qt-quick

How do I assign an `TextInput` to an int, in qml?

int new_span_seconds

```
TextInput {
        id: editor
        width: 80
        height: 17
        color: "white"
        font.bold: true; font.pixelSize: 14
        text: "21"
        horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

    }

    Keys.forwardTo: [ (returnKey), (editor)]

    Item {
        id: returnKey
        Keys.onReturnPressed: new_span_seconds = editor. <<< ?  >>>
        Keys.onEnterPressed:  new_span_seconds = editor. <<< ?  >>>
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

It's just a piece of Javascript

```
Keys.onReturnPressed: new_span_seconds = parseInt(editor.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of a jenky part of `js`, which allows you to convert a string into an integer by "multiplying" it. F.ex. `let foo = "2"; let bar = foo * 1`.

Here's how it looks when applied to the specific code you gave:

```
TextInput {
        id: editor
        width: 80
        height: 17
        color: "white"
        font.bold: true; font.pixelSize: 14
        text: "21"
        horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter

    }

    Keys.forwardTo: [ (returnKey), (editor)]

    Item {
        id: returnKey
        Keys.onReturnPressed: new_span_seconds = editor.text * 1
        Keys.onEnterPressed:  new_span_seconds = editor.text * 1
    }
}
```